# MySql query using two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this query to work, I just want to display record where Physio Reference (from table 1) equals `SESS_MEMBER_ID` (from a members table in MySQL).

I'm not sure exactly how to do this as I'm still grasping the concept of php. I'm not sure if you have to put some code at the end to tell it that the field is from the table `members`.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA 
      WHERE IASubmitted= 'no' 
      AND PhysioReference = 'SESS_MEMBER_ID'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**Members table**

> member_id,    firstname,  lastname,   login,  passwd,

**IA Table**

> Reference,  Forename,   Surname,    DOB,    PhysioReference,

Thanks in advance

update

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA tb1,members tb2 where tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id and tb2.member_id=SESS_MEMBER_ID";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: post the table structures in the question !!

Comment: please mention the relation about these two tables

Comment: where records from the IA table meet the criteria, I want them to be displayed in my table. the table section works fine its just my query.

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS_TABLE ON IA.PhysioReference = MEMBERS_TABLE.PhysioReference
WHERE IA.IASubmitted= 'no' AND IA.PhysioReference = 'SESS_MEMBER_ID'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

More information about INNER JOIN:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: I have tried this and changed the relevant fields to match those in the tables but no luck. I have put the amended code at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM IA tb1,MEMBERS_TABLE tb2 where tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id and tb2.member_id=SESS_MEMBER_ID";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: tb2 pk :member_id and tb1 FK : PhysioReference  then only the above query applicable

Answer (score 0):

This Inner joined worked with my session varibles

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id='{$_SESSION["MEMBER_ID"]}';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```